# Can i determine the species that's on a colony ship in stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

**Update**: The Clarke patch of June 1 solved the problem.

It seems that once you have built a colony ship, there seems to be no way to check which species it transports from clicking on the ship. This isn't a problem early in the game, when you have just your starting species, but later, you build lots of colony ships in lots of places, and it's be nice to click on a ship and actually see which planet type it can colonize.

My workaround right now is remember the ship's name, click any planet, click the colonize button in the planet UI, and find the ship in the resulting list.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can in the upcoming Clark patch. It's already available in beta in steam, and will go live in the following couple of weeks. Colony ship will show a pop that's on the ship - race, traits, ethos.

Comment: Tried the patch just for this. Yes, this is much better.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm The beta patch is now live, this should probably be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't check which ship has which species as colonists. But as you described, you can select the planet and click colonize on its interface.

Instead of remembering the ships name, just take a look at all the info there. It shows you all available colony ships, the species they carry, what the ship is currently doing and the habitability of said species on the planet. I find this much more comfortable to use and don't even worry about individual colony ships anymore.

This is especially handy when you build colony ships in sectors as those don't even appear on the ships list in the outliner.

So here is the step-by-step of how I do it:

1. pause the game
2. check every planet I want to colonize, hovering over the yellow or green globe will show you which species in your empire is best suited, make a note for each.
3. I order the the appropriate colony ships
4. Wait for colony ships to complete
5. Select the colonize button in the planet interface and select an idle colony ship of the best suited species.

Comment: One should, in 2016, assume a game wouldn't you require to use pen and paper anymore. Why can't the colonize button just give me a list of suitable planets, ordered by distance, and clicking on one will build a colony ship there, send it to the current planet, and colonize it?

Comment: That would have been the best solution, yes. But the interface has more glaring weaknesses (having to build every ship manually one by one, anyone?). It's paradox, they need time and community input to make their interface truly great. While they have many good ideas, they often miss significant weaknesses.